# Access denied for all users when they try to connect to SharePoint

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-online

User deleted a group out off people and groups and since then all users are getting an access denied error when they try to connect to SharePoint.

They believed the group to be domain\users but I have added this back but has not worked.

really appreciate your help on this matter what information do you guys require ?

Comment: im confused about the title ".. all years.."? Is that what you mean or is that a typo?

Comment: Hey I have the same problem, i put the NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users as visitor group but the error continues.. any Idea?

Comment: I have the same issue too; have you got any solution

Answer (score 4):

It may well be that you had a group which contained "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users" to give all logged in users access to SharePoint. This is a common way to allow everyone read access at the root site of an Intranet, for example. The most common group which would contain that entity would be "[site name] Visitors".